# Rollback safe set of move operations through bash

Tags: bash, file, file-io

Trying to create a bash script that lets me move the three files I have below into new files.

```
x.file -> 1.file
y.file -> 2.file
z.file -> 3.file
```

Now the only problem is that, for one of my programs to work the relational consistency between the files needs to be consistent. If only `x.file` was transferred to `1.file`, my stack would not work, as the relational consistency between all the files is broken.

Is there a way to create a function in bash that lets me do the entire set of moves consistently and were there to be a failure for whatever reason, default to the old files?

Comment: This is a relatively trivial task, why do you think the other move operations would fail. What is wrong in just renaming these files back to back?

Comment: It's not just if one of the operations fails; the three operations *together* is not atomic, so there is a brief window where `1.file`, `y.file`, and `z.file`, for example, exist, and that could be a problem for the system in question.

Comment: When does your system actually stop looking for `{x,y,z}.file` and start looking for `{1,2,3}.file`?

Comment: @chepner it's always looking for the {1,2,3} file

Comment: I want to automate the update of said files across a distributed system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that it is OK for the new file names to exist along side the old file names. Instead of moving them individually, create hard links with the new names, then remove the old links.

```
ln x.file 1.file
ln y.file 2.file
ln z.file 3.file
rm x.file y.file z.file
```

This may need some adjustment depending on when your system actually starts looking for `{1,2,3}.file` instead of `{x,y,z}.file`. For instance, if seeing `1.file` implies that `{2,3}.file` should exist, make the link to `1.file` *last*.

```
ln z.file 3.file
ln y.file 2.file
ln x.file 1.file
rm x.file y.file z.file
```

Another idea (if possible) is to have your program look for a specific *directory* that contains only `{1,2,3}.file`. Then you can move the files into a temporary directory, then atomically rename the directory.

```
# Assuming the program looks for real/1.file, real/2.file, and real/3.file
mkdir tmp
mv x.file tmp/1.file
mv y.file tmp/2.file
mv z.file tmp/3.file
mv tmp real
```

Otherwise, you may need to implement some explicit locking, or (if such a thing exists) a file system that supports transactions.

Comment: so let's assume that the system switches off right after linking y.file to 2.file. Does this mean that the relational consistency is preserved, and why?

Comment: The solutions with `ln` were presented when I assumed that your code was currently looking for x/y/z and you wanted to transition to 1/2/3. But if you are blocking until 1/2/3 exist, you'll either have to use the directory trick at the end of the answer (so that there is one atomic rename to watch for) or you'll have to modify your program to block until 1/2/3 are all available, rather than assuming that if one is available then all should be.

Comment: There is no general way to move/rename/create multiple files simultaneously.